# {"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."} when calling web service

Tags: web-services, soap

I am attempting to bind to a web service at run time and call a simple method to get this code working, and get the above error message when I try to get the reply from the web service. Below is the following code, first how I'm invoking the service:

```
    Public Sub BeginInvoke(invokeCompleted As AsyncCallback)
    Dim invoke As New DelegateInvokeService(AddressOf Me.InvokeWebService)

    Dim result As IAsyncResult = invoke.BeginInvoke(invokeCompleted, Nothing)
End Sub

Public Function EndInvoke(result As IAsyncResult) As String
    Dim asyncResult = DirectCast(result, AsyncResult)
    Dim message As ReturnMessage = DirectCast(asyncResult.GetReplyMessage(), ReturnMessage)

    Return message.ReturnValue.ToString()
End Function

Public Function InvokeWebService() As String
    Try
        'Create the request
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CreateWebRequest()

        'write the soap envelope to request stream
        Using s As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            Using writer As New StreamWriter(s)
                writer.Write(CreateSoapEnvelope())
            End Using
        End Using

        'get the response from the web service
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

        Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

        Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)

        Dim str = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Return StripResponse(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

Now for building the soap package and web request:

```
Private Function CreateSoapEnvelope() As String
    Dim method As String = "<" & WebMethod & " xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">"
    Dim params As String = Parameters.Aggregate(String.Empty, Function(current, param) current & "<" & param.Name & ">" & param.Value & "</" & param.Name & ">")

    method &= params & "</" & WebMethod & ">"

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(SoapEnvelope)
    sb.Insert(sb.ToString().IndexOf("</soap:Body>"), method)

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function

Private Function CreateWebRequest() As HttpWebRequest
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(Url), HttpWebRequest)
    If WSServiceType = ServiceType.WCF Then
        request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", """http://tempuri.org/" & WCFContractName & "/" & WebMethod & """")
    Else
        request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", """http://tempuri.org/" & WebMethod & """")
    End If

    request.Headers.Add("To", Url)

    request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=""utf-8"""
    request.Accept = "text/xml"
    request.Method = "POST"
    Return request
End Function
```

The **SoapEnvelope** variable looks like so:

```
Private Const SoapEnvelope As String = "<soap:Envelope " & _
    "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " & _
    "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' " & _
    "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" & _
    "<soap:Body></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
```

And this is how I'm calling the above invoking:

```
Protected Sub GoButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GoButton.Click
    _oClient = New SoapClient()

    Dim params As New List(Of SoapClient.Parameter)
    params.Add(New SoapClient.Parameter() With {.Name = "str", .Value = "Richard"})

    With _oClient
        .Url = "http://localhost:7659/WebServices/SampleService.asmx"
        .WebMethod = "HelloWorld"
        .WSServiceType = SoapClient.ServiceType.Traditional
        .Parameters = params
    End With

    _oClient.BeginInvoke(AddressOf InvokeCompleted)
End Sub

Public Sub InvokeCompleted(result As IAsyncResult)
    ErrorMessage.Text = _oClient.EndInvoke(result)
End Sub
```

The error is generated on this line in **InvokeWebService**

```
'get the response from the web service
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: What in the world are you doing, and why don't you do it via "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: I'm in a position where I need to be able to bind to a web service dynamically, instead of adding multiple web service references to my project

Comment: Why in the world are you doing it this way? Your code won't work if the namespace prefixes are different, for instance. Where did you get this idea? Is this the WSE `SoapClient` class? That's obsolete and all but unsupported! There have to be a dozen better ways of accomplishing what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem with my sample web service I was testing with, once I fixed that error the above code works beautifully.